# How to schedule threads in java whose tasks depend on one another?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my first attempt at multithreading after learning about threads (in theory, heh) in my OS class at school, and I think the way I've gone about doing what I'm trying to do is bad practice/sloppy.

I'm parallelizing a minimax algorithm by spawning a separate thread for each branch of the game on which the algorithm is set to run. The scheduling part of this is a little tricky; as the algorithm deepens iteratively, and I want depth consistency across all the threads.

So, first I have a master thread which spawns a subthread for each available move in the game:

```
    public void run(){
        // initializes all the threads
        for (AlphaBetaMultiThread t : threadList) {
            t.start();
        }
        try { //This won't ever happen; the subthreads run forever
            evals = 0;
            for (AlphaBetaMultiThread t : threadList) {
                t.join();
                evals += t.evals;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error joining threads: " + e);
        }
    }
```

The thread passes itsself to the constructor so each subthread so that the threads can access the master thread's maxDepth property and signalDepth methods:

```
    public synchronized void signalDepth(){
        signals++;
        if (signals % threadList.length() == 0){
            if (verbose)
                System.out.println(toString());
            depth++;
        }
    }
```

And finally, here's the subthread evaluation process. Whenever it's ahead of the rest of the threads, it lowers its own priority, and then yields until all the subthreads have signalled.

```
public void run() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true){
        if (depth >= master.maxDepth) {
            this.setPriority(4);
            this.yield();
            break;
        } else {
            this.setPriority(5);
        }
        eval = -1*alphabeta(0, infHolder.MIN, infHolder.MAX);
        manager.signalDepth();
        depth += 1;
    }
}
```

Besides the fact that my implementation seems not to work at all right now (still trying to figure out why), I really feel as if what I'm doing isn't the standard way of doing things. My intuition is that there are probably all kinds of built-in multithreading libraries that could make my life a lot easier, but I don't really know what I'm looking for.

Oh, I'm also getting a warning that Thread.destroy() is deprecated (which is how I'm planning on destroying everything after the computer player finally plays its move).

I guess my question is this: what should I be using to manage my subthreads?

edit: Oh, and if there's stuff I've left out that is relevant to my question, feel free to look at my complete code on github: https://github.com/cowpig/MagneticCave
The relevant files are GameThread and AlphaBetaMultiThread.
I apologize for my cluelessness!

Another edit: I want the threads to deepen iteratively forever, until the gamePlayer object (the one creating the master thread) decides it is time to choose a move-- at which it will access the list of moves and find the one with the highest evaluation. This means .join() won't work, unless I create a new set of threads for every depth iteration, but then that would require a lot more overhead (I think) so I don't really want to have to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Java 5 introduced a slew of useful concurrency constructs. One in particular you might want to research is [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). It is a synchronization aid that allows multiple threads to wait on each other to reach a common, barrier point (in your case, that would be the master depth).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Thread.join() to wait for the sub-threads, which should just exit when done. No need for Thread.destroy() at all, and no need for fiddling with priorities either.

Comment: I guess I should clarify why I don't want to do this in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using collections of raw `Thread` instances for this, you should be submitting `Runnable` instances to an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).  If all your threads are computing results of some kind, you probably want to use `Callable<?>` and [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).

If you have a dependency graph of `Runnable`s, I'd recommend using `ListenableFuture` from the  excellent Guava library.  See the [`ListenableFuture` explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) wiki article for details.

Answer (score 0):

If [dataflow graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming) representation is suitable for your task, you can make use of my dataflow library [df4j](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j).